# angularjs custom directive not working in visualforce

Tags: angularjs, salesforce, visualforce

I am new in salesforce and trying to implement custom directive of angularjs in visualforce page, but its does not work. Its displaying salesforce page UI.

Please refer the below code and suggest me what should I do.

### directive:

angular.module('nimbus').directive('customFooter', function () {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            templateUrl: 'tpl/footer.html',
            controller: ['$scope', '$filter', '$http', '$timeout', 'stats', '$ngBootbox' ,'$templateCache' , '$sce' , '$interval' , footerController],
            controllerAs: "footerController"
        };
    });

### calling for directive:

```
 <custom-footer></custom-footer>
```

### footer.html

```
 <footer class="map_data" resizable="true" on-resize="resize($evt, $ui)" handle="n" handle-id="handle" min-height="37" max-height="450" ng-show="showFooter==true">

    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="head_row">
                <div class="col-md-7">
                    <div class="nav_content">
                        <div class="main_select">
                            <label>Data Source</label>
                            <select class="large" data-ng-model="selectedDs" data-ng-change="dataSourceChanged(selectedDs)">
                                <option ng-repeat="(key, value) in filterSortNumericDs(dbSource)" value="{{key}}">{{key}}</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                        <ul>
                            <li ng-hide="selectedDataSource.unmappedData.length==0">

                                <select data-ng-options="md.id as md.value for md in mapData" data-ng-model="selectedMapData" data-ng-change="mapDataChanged()"></select>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <label>Summarize by</label>

                                <select class="medium" ng-disabled="selectedDataSource.type == 'Personnel'  " data-ng-options="sd.id as sd.value for sd in summarizeData | filter:{isActive:'true'} " data-ng-model="selectedSummarizeData" data-ng-change="dataLevelChanged()"></select>
                            </li>
                            <li class="paddind_top3">
                                <input name="" type="radio" ng-value="1" ng-model="selectedView" ng-disabled="selectedSummarizeData == 1" ng-change="changeCodeLabel()" />
                                <span class="blue">Code</span>
                            </li>
                            <li class="paddind_top3">
                                <input name="" type="radio" ng-value="2" ng-model="selectedView" ng-disabled="selectedSummarizeData == 1" ng-change="changeCodeLabel()" />
                                <span class="blue">Label</span>
                            </li>
                            <div class="clearfix"></div>
                        </ul>
                        <div class="clearfix"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-4 pull-right">
                    <div class="input-group footerSearch">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="{{searchPlaceholder}}" ng-model="searchText" ng-change="refreshData()" />
                        <span class="input-group-btn">
                            <button class="btn btn-default" type="button"></button>
                        </span>
                    </div>

                    <div style="display:none;" class="drop_panel" ng-click="toggleFooter()"><a href="#" class="drop_btn"></a></div>



                    <!-- /input-group -->
                    <!-- Drop Bottom -->
                    <!-- <div class="drop_panel"><a href="#" class="drop_btn"></a></div>-->
                </div>

                <div class="col-lg-4 pull-right" ng-show="selectedSummarizeData >= 2  ">
                    <div class="nav_content">
                        <ul style="padding:0px;">
                            <li class="pull-right padding0" style="padding:0px;">
                                <!-- <label>Show</label>
                                <select>
                                    <option>Change</option>
                                </select>
                                <select>
                                    <option>% Change</option>
                                </select> -->
                                <!-- <select>
                                    <option>% Deviation</option>
                                </select> -->

                                <div class="dropdown deviationContainer">
                                    <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
                                        % Deviation
                                        <span class="caret"></span>
                                    </button>


                                    <ul role="menu" class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" ng-show="devaitionColumns.length > 0 ">
                                        <li ng-repeat="dc in devaitionColumns">
                                            <label>
                                                <input type="checkbox" ng-model="dc.check" /> {{dc.columnName}}
                                            </label>
                                        </li>
                                    </ul>

                                </div>


                            </li>
                        </ul>
                        <div class="clearfix"></div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- /input-group -->
                    <!-- Drop Bottom -->
                    <!-- <div class="drop_panel"><a href="#" class="drop_btn"></a></div>-->
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="filed_data">

        <!--  <div id="grid1" ui-grid="gridOptions"  ui-grid-tree-view  ui-grid-resize-columns class="grid"></div> -->
        <!--  <div id="myGrid" style="height: 90%;" class="ag-fresh"></div> -->
        <div id="grid1" ag-grid="gridOptions" class="ag-fresh" style="height: 100%;"></div>
        <div ag-grid="gridOptionsBottom" class="ag-fresh" style="height: 40px;"></div>



    </div>

    <div id="dataBrowserOverlay" class="dataBrowserOverlay">
        <div class="dbLoaderContainer">
            <div class="DbLoader-spinner"></div>
        </div>
    </div>

</footer>
```

### Output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need any of the salesforce's UI put this at the top of the visual force page:

```
<apex:page showChat="false"  sidebar="false" docType="html-5.0" showHeader="false" standaradstylesheets="false" >
```

Comment: Thanks for reply Cloxure. I have tried as u suggested but it's not working for me.

Comment: Can you post the complete code of the visual force page where you are using the directive?